# How could these aquatic humans survive and reproduce?

Tags: humans, humanoid, reproduction, sea-creatures, mermaid

The aquatic humans resemble regular terrestrial humans almost perfectly as adults. This means they have hands, feet, and all of their bodyparts identically to humans (*H. sapiens sapiens*)

As children (the life stage before the adults), they grow and look like fish. By this, I mean that they have traits found in fish, such as fins, scales, and gills, which also develop in the way it does in fish (specifically the live-bearing fish). The children also have a humanoid form, which means that they have limbs arranged like in a human

They transform into adults with a quick tadpole-like metamorphosis, similar to the metamorphosis of frogs. During this metamorphosis, most of their structures change from what they were in the child stage to what they are in the adult stage. This metamorphosis happens when the children are around 13 years old, measured from when they are born

The children are born from large fish-like animals, that resemble fish in their appearance, anatomy, and physiology. These animals also have a uterus (in which the embryos of the humans develop), and a large mouth (in which the children of the humans are protected after birth). The fish-like parents would give birth through the cervix (the exit of the uterus) and cloaca (which the cervix is attached to, in addition to the uterus)

What is the simplest and most plausible way for a biological life-cycle to feature this strange apparent xenogenesis? Specifically, what are the steps of reproduction/growth that allow new individuals of the stages detailed above to appear?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130091/discussion-on-question-by-ichthys-king-how-could-these-aquatic-humans-survive-an).

Comment: @Pelinore "Simple: plain, basic, or uncomplicated in form, nature, or design; without much decoration or ornamentation" You can't randomly add extra unnecessary stages and still have the solution be the simplest

Comment: There is still at least 2 perfectly plausible minimalist options here, the human form becomes the big fishy thing that spawns the things they develop from / or the big fishy things reproduce themselves (& there are 2 options there, it can be sexual or asexual, so perhaps it's 3 options in all) & the human forms are essentially drones of some sort / but *'simplest and most plausible"* does help a little, cuts out the endless range of the possible at least, & the drone option requires explaining how their useful to their progenitor so we can perhaps refine it to the one option, so OK I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question describes a multi-stage lifecycle with a crucial missing step:

1. Pre-natal - fish-people embryos developing in uterus of large "fish-like" animals
2. Transition 1: Birth
3. Brood-ling - very young fish-people stay with fish-like parent for protection
4. Juvenile - childhood phase with young fish-people free swimming the ocean
5. Transition 2: Metamorphosis
6. Terrestrial - adult fish-people on land, living like normal humans
7. *Transition 3: Something happens to get us back to step 1*

There are already some good answers here, but I wanted to go somewhere different.

**what if the fish-people are parasitic?**

As described in the question, the terrestrial stage fish-people are adults. By that I understand it to mean this is where the babies get made. This works just like the human process up to the point of conception with one notable difference: to successfully get from birth to metamorphosis in sufficient numbers to ensure species viability, we need some degree of *r*-selection so the fish-people mother will have to release eggs in larger numbers than humans do.

At this point, the female’s body needs to make some changes. This will be best accomplished if her body relies more heavily on instinct than intelligence as she will have to die as part of the process. For balance, let’s have the male die of accelerated decrepitude shortly after “the deed”. His job is done anyway.

Now, the female has to get to the sea and find her fish.

*the fish: The “large fish-like animal” from the question is, normally, just a fish. Perfectly normal with a few not-uncommon properties: (1) it’s a large predator, (2) it uses suction feeding to swallow prey whole (no tearing or chewing please), & (3) it’s a viviparous (or ovoviviparous) mouthbrooder.*

This makes the female’s job a bit easier. All she has to do it get eaten by the female form of this fish. Internally, her body has built an indigestible barrier around her uterus and a few newly-developed organs. The female herself is digested but her womb latches on near the fish’s cloaca. It embeds itself to the wall with a cervix now leading to the cloaca. It will need to secrete something that tricks the fish’s body into thinking it belongs there and that the fish is currently pregnant (if the fish was already pregnant, it will also need to force spontaneous ejection of the undeveloped fish embryos/eggs). We have now returned to step 1 in the lifecycle with fish-people embryos developing in the (newly acquired) uterus of a large fish-like animal (“fish-like” because it’s been heavily modified by our fish-people parasite).

Step 2 is straightforward. Once the fish-people are mature enough for birth, they are released via the cervix and exit through the cloaca. Step 3 takes advantage of the fish’s own instincts to care for its brood.

*And the circle of life continues…*

**caveat:** The lifecycle proposed in the question is going to be complex, probably too complex to evolve naturally. The parasitic model here is an attempt to create a more realistic (but still very unlikely) version.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like insects but with multiple metamorphosis stages. Metarmorph from fish to human within a cocoon or sac. Then return to the water and metamorph to the other fish form when the human body ages.

So there'd be two pupa stages instead of one.

So you life cycle would be

Egg

Larva (aquatic)

Pupa

Human Adult (terrestrial)

Pupa

Breeding Stage Adult (aquatic)

Answer (score 0):

### Genetic Engineering.

The easiest way such a complex series of metamorphoses are created would be through Genetic Engineering. If you have humans who are indistinguishable from us today, and they have smart brains and all intelligence required to be like us, then it stands to reason they are us, and at some point in the future we Genetically Engineer ourselves to grow in this way.

It may actually be plausible, as we do resemble fish in our embryonic state. This is because evolution is a highly additive process which builds on DNA code previously established, and as we come from fish we do resemble them to a degree early in our development.

It would be challenging to envisage a natural scenario where such a complex life-cycle is formed - the only natural occurrence of similar (but simpler) scenarios is in some insect and amphibian species, which transform into flying or land/based forms in order to find a mate (having evolved from early fish or insect origins). However, humans are mammals and need conditions that we have experienced in order to become like 'us'.

In your case, it is more conceivable that a 'mad' scientist experimented (illegally) with human embryos to see how long a fish-like state is prolonged, perhaps with the outcome that a child up to 13 is fish-like, and to discard mammalian features and return to this state after mating. However, it would be likely after many false-starts, copious effort and many life-cycles with constant attention and experimentation.

Comment: But how would the life cycle specifically work?

Comment: @IchthysKing I would imagine it doesn't unless it's within very controlled conditions. A fish state > birth to fish is simple. However the discarding of gills and the formation of lungs, and fish to arms/fingers is a lot harder. The transition probably needs to be in a highly controlled, shallow shore or tank. Once 'human', after mating, they need to regain their fish features. Perhaps however rather than losing lungs and gaining gills, they are more akin to whales and seals, which hold their breath (and are mammals), to give birth underwater.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, what are the steps of reproduction/growth that allow new individuals of the stages detailed above to appear?

I would go with the age of sexual maturity/procreation *before* the age of metamorphosis into humanoid shape, the latter being sterile.

Reasons:

1. transforming back from humanoid into a fish to procreate is one transformation too many
2. fishes usually have a much shorter age to sexual maturity than humans, thus arranging for things to fall like this is plausible
3. if the humanoid form is not sterile, then it creates the difficulty of "born from fish" vs "born from humanoid".

This leads to the question of what is the role of the humanoid stage into the picture, why the evolution let this stage to exist, since apparently is a waste of resources from the perspective of perpetuating the species?
The answer will relate a lot with the context of the world in which the evolution occurred (and is let as an exercise for the writer).

I'll mention that the above has at least some sort of precedent in the Niven's [Protector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protector_(novel)) - while not quite such a radical metamorphosis between fish/human stage, but still a sexual young stage followed by a mature sterile one (the latter acting as protectors for the younglings).

Now that I think, the pequeninos in [Speaker for the dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_for_the_Dead) also show the same pattern, except that the "tree" stage of their life is forced upon their species by the terraforming virus rather than a result of evolution.